# How find out a device's size and screen density specifier non-programatically

Tags: android, size, dpi, pixel-density

I want to know how to find out the correct combination of a device's size specifier (large, xlarge, xxlarge, etc) and screen pixel density specifier (hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, etc). Please explain the method using Oppo F3 as example because I defined many "values" folder but still on my Oppo F3 there are still some disproportions.

Comment: Step #1: Buy an Oppo F3. Step #2: Run an app that reports the `Configuration` information for screen size and density.

Comment: Is there a manual way ? Like look up a specific spec and get to know the specifiers from the spec ? I don't wanna have to run the app on every device that I consider to test on.

Comment: "I don't wanna have to run the app on every device that I consider to test on" -- well, first, most programmers do not need to worry about these values for "every device that I consider to test on". Second, installing an app and reading those values would be faster and more reliable than "look up a specific spec and get to know the specifiers from the spec".

Comment: The thing is I was able to know the phone is xxhdpi and I assumed large specifier because it is 5.5 inch phone but the phone did not respond to changes in values-large-xxhdpi. I even tried a configuration app but google defines the screen size specifier by "dp units" and the app doesn't report in those units.